# Pulseaudio Error X220 Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, ubuntu-14.04

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Lenovo X220 and it worked fine for two weeks without any issues. Now the Sound Devices are gone! They are not broken cause I can control them in the terminal with alsamixer but I can't switch to another device (for example Bluetooth). Everything worked absolutely fine but from one day to another its not working. Any ideas?

I already re-installed ALSA and PulseAudio but nothing changes...

Here is a screenshot from pulseaudio...
[image: pulseaudio dump]

Answer (score -1):

Broken files. For me, the solution was to delete `/home/USERNAME/.config/pulse`.

After that,

```
killall pulseaudio-daemons
```

and restart it with

```
pulseaudio &
```

.